# Problem in connecting the database in Cpanel

Tags: laravel

I am new in upload the laravel project in c Panel, now I have problem in connect the database , I am import migration in the phpMyAdmin in c panel but in registration I have an error :

**Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)**

this my phpMyAdmin in c panel:

[image]

and its my databse :
[image]

and this my env in file manger in c panel :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm the database server address. It is usually localhost but it might have a different address.
2. Usually when you make a database in CPanel you will also create a user with access permission on the new database. Try using that user.